# error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value (Return value of a function)

Tags: rust, reference

I can't figure out the problem with my code. I'm trying to make a CLI app to learn rust by doing a project and I keep getting error E0515
Here is my code:

```rust
use std::path::Display;
use std::fs;

fn read_file(path: &str) -> String {
    fs::read_to_string(path)
        .expect("Should have been able to read the file")
}

fn list_dir(path: &str) -> Vec<Display>{
    let paths = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();
    let mut dirs: Vec<Display> = vec![];
    for path in paths {
        dirs.push(path.unwrap().path().display());
    }
    dirs
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}",list_dir("C:").len())
}
```

The compiler tells me that i am returning a value that is referencing data owned by `list_dir` function:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
13 |         dirs.push(path.unwrap().path().display());
   |                   -------------------- temporary value created here
14 |     }
15 |     dirs
   |     ^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I tried some ways to change the return type of the function but none of them worked.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::path::Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Display.html) **borrows** a `Path`. You can tell it because it is generic over a lifetime (`Display<'a>`). However your problem is deeper. If you try doing something like this:

```rust
fn list_dir(path: &str) -> () {
    let paths = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();
    let mut dirs: Vec<Display> = vec![];
    for path in paths {
        dirs.push(path.unwrap().path().display());
    }
}
```

This will still **fail to compile** and you will get the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:13:19
   |
13 |         dirs.push(path.unwrap().path().display());
   |         ----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------ temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |         |         |
   |         |         creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
   |         borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

The problem here is that `fs::read_dir` returns an iterator, which yields [ReadDir](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.ReadDir.html) structs, from which you can take a [PathBuf](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html) (an **owned** representation of OS path) using method [ReadDir::path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html#method.path).

However you cannot **store references** to those `PathBuf`s, because they will be **dropped** on the next iteration.

Now you have to ask yourself, what do you want to do? If you wish to return a vector of those paths (which I guess is what you want), just return a `Vec<PathBuf>`. If you want to use `std::path::Display` implementation to get utf-8 representation of paths return a vector of `String`s and simply call `to_string` inside your `push` call.